# Need some guidance in regular expressions substring

Tags: regex, substr

Three string examples: (data is stored in a column called `a.metadata`)

> anything_before"subjectareas":[{"name":"\"I NEED THIS1\""anything_after

> anything_before"subjectareas":[{"displayName":"whatever","name":"\"I NEED THIS2\""anything_after

> anything_before"subjectareas":[{"displayName":"whatever - whatever","name":"\"I NEED THIS3\""anything_after

My output should be:

> I NEED THIS1

> I NEED THIS2

> I NEED THIS3

The words `subjectareas`, `name`, `displayName` can be used in the logic and case sensitive based expressions are OK.

I was trying a variety of things, including this below, but I can't get it to work.
`regexp_substr(a.metadata, '[^"subjectareas"]*[^"name":"\"]*[^\\]')`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like JSON. Are you dealing with JSON?

Comment: Can you share a few samples

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, yes JSON, but the entire metadata is in a Oracle Database column. Not in a flat-file to code in Python etc.

Comment: @JoeFerndz I did share 3  string examples. The actual string is much longer with things that doesn't matter. so I represented those as "anything_before" and "anything_after". Those can really be anything.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using a nested regexp_replace and two regexp_substr functions. It is ugly. There has to be a better way to do this:

regexp_replace(regexp_substr(regexp_substr(a.metadata, 'subjectareas[^\\]*\\[^\\]*', 1, 1, 'c'), '\\.*'),'\\|"')

Answer (score 0):

Use

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(a.metadata,
                     '"subjectareas":\[\{("[^"]*":"[^"]*",)*"name":"\W*"([^\\]*)',
                     1, 1, 'c', 2)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/6fblog/2). You get the second group value with the above `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

Comment: thanks .. it works. But what if the "displayName" came after the "name" ? In all my three examples, either there is no "displayName" or "name" came after "displayName".

Comment: @sush Then use `"subjectareas":\[\{("[^"]*":"[^"]*",)*"name":"\W*"([^\\]*)`. Have a look at https://regex101.com/r/6fblog/2

Comment: @sush +1 for the question anyway :)

Comment: I wanted to thank you earlier .. yes, it worked. But SO prevented me from just posting a thanks note :-)